# mysql DOUBLE with thousands separator

Tags: mysql, string, double

Is there any way to convert string to `DOUBLE` format when inserting new record, I want to strip it out or ignore if it exists in value when do insert in database.

```
INSERT INTO  table1  (measure) VALUES val1
```

`val1` can contain `20000` or `20,000`.  Can I do it with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

You must first remove the separators by using `REPLACE`.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (measure) VALUES (REPLACE(val1, ',', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

As njk mentioned, you can use REPLACE function, but to ignore if it exists in value, you use INSERT IGNORE.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (measure) VALUES (REPLACE(val1, ',', ''))
```

The IGNORE keyword will not insert the new record if the value is found ONLY IF the column has an unique index defined or a primary key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace